# Complex cubic roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

If $w^3=1$

Solve $(1-w)(1-w^2)(1-w^4)(1-w^5)$

I am not sure how to go about this question, I attempted expand the equation and simplify it using the basic roots of unity theorems, but it was . I am asking if anyone has a simple way of solving equations of these sort.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the following $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ and $\omega^3=1$. For example using the second property, we can write $\omega^5=\omega^2$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $w\ne 1$. Then $1+w+w^2=0$.
Also $w^4=w$ and $w^5=w^2$. Your product is
$$[(1-w)(1-w^2)]^2=(2-w-w^2)^2=3^2=9.$$

More generally, let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. That is
$\zeta^n=1$ and $\zeta^d\ne1$ for $0<d<n$. Then
$$X^n-1=(X-1)(X-\zeta)(X-\zeta^2)\cdots(X-\zeta^{n-1}).$$
Dividing by $X-1$ and letting $X\to1$ gives
$$n=(1-\zeta)(1-\zeta^2)\cdots(1-\zeta^{n-1}).$$
Your formula is the square of this with $n=3$.